# Implement file upload with TCP in Java

Tags: java, file-upload

I'm trying to implement a code for my program that will allow the user to choose the file from their local drive, and then they can press to upload to the server

Basically I will have to accomplish using with TCP where I will have `Client.java` and `Server.java`

In `Client.java` would include all my `GUI` part of the program, and the file that will be send to the `Server.java`

In `Server.java` All it does is listen to the client.java and wait to get the specified file with the path and get it and put them in the local folder

So both `Client.java` and `Server.java` are in the same computer

[image]

I have looked into this one [Transfer file over TCP](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/139154-transfer-a-file-over-tcp/) but what it really does is that it will get the data from the client (Data as a text only) and it will write it into a file, but my question is if I would implement the same from that link, how would I implement to make it get the file and make another copy of the file in the local directory?

Comment: Send the path of the file to the server. Then read the file in the server, and write its content to another file. Try something and if you get stuck, come back here with a specific question.

Comment: I do not really get your question. Are `Client` and `Server` on the same machine?

Comment: @home Yes sir, both are in the same machine and I'm writing the code using Eclipse

Comment: @JBNizet can you suggest me where do I look for some documentation about that? I'm new to Java and this is my last assignment for this course.

Comment: Type "Java IO tutorial" in Google, and the first link should be an Oracle tutorial about Java IO.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks I'm going to look into that now. Appricated your help :)